# tensorflow session() takes long time

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I am playing a bit with tensorflow. I calculate the intersection over union for my predictions, and to convert it into a "readable" format I use the .eval() function using the following code.

```
def iou(y_true, y_pred,label : int):
    y_true = K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true), label), K.floatx())
    y_pred = K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_pred), label), K.floatx())
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    union = K.sum(y_true) + K.sum(y_pred) - intersection
    return K.switch(K.equal(union, 0), 1.0, intersection / union)


def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    num_labels = (K.int_shape(y_pred)[-1] )
    all_iou = []
    total_iou = tf.convert_to_tensor(0, dtype='float32')
    for label in range(num_labels):
        total_iou = total_iou + iou(y_true, y_pred, label)
    return total_iou / num_labels

one_ious, zero_ious, mean_ious, accuracies=[], [], [], []

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for it in range(len(y_test)):
        tmp=iou(y_test[it],y_pred[it],1)
        one_ious.append(tmp.eval())
        tmp=iou(y_test[it],y_pred[it],0)
        zero_ious.append(tmp.eval())
        tmp=mean_iou(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test[it]),tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred[it]))
        mean_ious.append(tmp.eval())
```

The problem is that it takes ages (it might take more than half an hour to do that for 1500 arrays of 16k points).

I was wondering if any of you could help me to understand why it is taking so long, how to fix it and also if there is any better way to do the same thing.

Comment: Hi @Federico, welcome to StackOverflow! While your introduction was really polite it adds noise and distracts from the question. You can thank people with upvotes and accepting their answers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to partially solve this problem. The slowest parts of the function were the 3 .eval() in the for loop, which took respectively about 5, 1.5 and 1.5 seconds on my computer, ending up in about 3 hours and a half to perform this task for 1600 arrays.

Simply appending the results to a python list and applying the .eval() functions on the final list allows to perform the same task in about 3  minutes.

```
tmp1, tmp2, tmp3=[], [], []
import time
start=time.time()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for it in range(len(y_test)):
        tmp1.append(iou(y_test[it],y_pred[it]),1)
        tmp2.append(iou(y_test[it],y_pred[it]),0)
        tmp3.append(mean_iou(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test[it]),tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred[it])))
    one_ious=tf.convert_to_tensor(tmp1)
    zero_ious=tf.convert_to_tensor(tmp2)
    mean_ious=tf.convert_to_tensor(tmp3)
    tmp1, tmp2, tmp3=[], [], []
    one_ious=one_ious.eval()
    zero_ious=zero_ious.eval()
    mean_ious=mean_ious.eval()
end=time.time()
print('time: {}'.format(end-start))
```

Not sure this is the best method to do the job, but it works. If any has a better input I would be very happy to hear it.